# AppEngine Task Queue exception upon message too big

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After reading [TaskOptions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html) and [Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.html) from the AppEngine Javadoc API, I can't find which exception gets thrown when the payload of the Task exceeds the limit of 100KB. Where could I find this information?

**UPDATE:** Filed a request for a [more specific exception](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5921).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer looking at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueImpl.java).

```
if (txn != null &&
        bulkAddRequest.encodingSize() > QueueConstants.maxTransactionalRequestSizeBytes()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          String.format("Transactional add may not be larger than %d bytes: %d bytes requested.",
              QueueConstants.maxTransactionalRequestSizeBytes(),
              bulkAddRequest.encodingSize()));
    }
```